# Each number in $S\subseteq \{1,\ldots,2n\}$ does not divide another one, with $|S|= n$. In how many ways?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, asymptotics

Let $f(n)$ be the number of subsets $S\subseteq \{1,2,\ldots,2n\}$ such that $|S|=n$ and $a$ does not divide $b$ whenever $a,b \in S$ are distinct. Can we evaluate $f(n)$, at least asimptotically?

The question is related to [this other one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409234/each-number-in-a-subset-s-subseteq-1-ldots-2n-does-not-divide-another-one), where I had a more complicated (and unuseful) solution. In particular, is it true that $f(n)=o(n)$? Moreover, is it true that $f(n)$ is definitively bigger than $(\ln n)^k$ for any constant $k$?

**Edit:** the first conjecture has been proved to be false (see the answer of Robert below). Then, can we say that $\ln f(n)=O(n)$?

Comment: See OEIS sequence A174094 (https://oeis.org/A174094) which has $f(n)$ for $n = 1..46$.  The logarithmic scatterplot makes it plausible that $f(n) \sim a \exp(b n)$ for some $a,b$ with $b > 0$, but very implausible that  $f(n) = o(n)$.

Comment: See my blogpost regarding this question: https://anuragbishnoi.wordpress.com/2017/11/02/on-a-famous-pigeonhole-problem/. As per my knowledge, asymptotically the best lower bound on $f(n)$ is $2^{n/3}$ while the best upper bound is about $2^{0.78n}$ (see the comments). It would be really interesting for me to close this gap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to get a lower bound that grows exponentially.  Start with 
the subset $S = \{n+1, \ldots, 2n\}$.   Take an arbitrary subset $J \subseteq \{j \in S:\; j \text{ even},\; j > 4n/3\}$ and replace each $j \in J$ by $j/2$.   This gives  $2^{1 + \lfloor (n-1)/3 \rfloor}$ solutions.

EDIT: For the second question: of course $f(n)$ is at most the number of all subsets of $\{1, \ldots, 2n\}$, which is $2^{2n}$.

Comment: Again, very clear and simple! Thank you Robert

Comment: how did you come up with $4n/3$?

Comment: Needed $3 (j/2)$ not to be in $S$.