# Choose n+1 numbers from 1 to 2n. Prove that among the chosen numbers, there is always a pair of different numbers (a,b) such that a|b or b|a

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pigeonhole-principle

My reasoning so far is:

If the number 1 is chosen, we are done since 1 divides any number.

If 2 is chosen, then the remaining n numbers to choose will either be all odd (including 1) or contain an even number.

I do not know how to progress from here.  Does it require the pigeonhole principle?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any number from 1 to $2n$ is of the form (power of 2)*odd. How many options do you have for the odd part?

Comment: @CatalinZara How do you mean?

Comment: @CatalinZara Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$n + 1$ numbers are picked at random from $2n$ integers $1, 2, 3,\dots , 2n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3588969/n-1-numbers-are-picked-at-random-from-2n-integers-1-2-3-dots-2n) - found by clicking through various linked questions in the "Linked" section on the RHS. Note the answer there uses a quite similar proof technique as in the currently accepted answer here. Also, the listed duplicates there, and other Linked questions, provide more basic duplicate questions to this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that any $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ can be expressed in the form $2^{k} \times O$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ and $O$ is the **greatest positive odd divisor** of $n$. This can be quite easily proved.

Now, consider any integer $z$ from $1,2,3, \ldots, 2n$. The greatest positive odd divisor of $z$ must be one of $1,3,5,7,\dots,2n - 1$. Hence the greatest positive divisor of $z$ can take any one of $n$ such values.

Now, let the pigeons be the $n + 1$ integers selected and the $n$ pigeonholes correspond to the possible values of the greatest positive odd divisor. Place each integer in the sequence $1,2,3,\ldots,2n$ into its unique pigeonhole.

By the pigeonhole principle, when $n+1$ integers are selected from $1,2,3,\ldots,2n$ it is guaranteed that two integers are selected from the same pigeonhole. Let $a,b$ be the integers selected from the same pigeonhole and let $O$ be the greatest positive odd divisor of $a,b$. Assume WLOG $a \lt b$ such that $a = 2^{r} \times O$ and $b = 2^{s} \times O$ where $r \lt s$ and $r,s \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$. Now,

$$ \frac{b}{a} = \frac{2^{s} \times O}{2^{r} \times O}$$
$$ \implies b = 2^{s - r}\times a$$

By the closure of integers under subtraction, $s - r \in \mathbb{Z}$ and hence $2^{s - r} \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then it immediately follows by the definition of divisibility that $a|b$.

Comment: That is very interesting. Thank you.  Can you show me a proof of the 2^k * O property?

Comment: Look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25914/proof-by-strong-induction-n-2a-b-b-odd-every-natural-a-product-of-an  .Looking at this proof, you can easily get inspiration to prove it for the greatest positive odd divisor.

Comment: So speaking informally, if I took an even number, I can just continue to divide it by two until I reached an odd number?

Comment: And additionally, that first odd number you reach after continually dividing by two would be the greatest odd divisor?

Comment: In some sense yes, suppose $n$ is even and $O$ is the greatest positive odd divisor. Then for some $k_{0} \in \mathbb{Z}$, $n = k_{0} \times O$. Surely $k_{0}$ cannot be odd since then $k_{0} \times O$ would be odd and would be greater than $O$ and still be a positive odd divisor contradicting that $O$ is the greatest positive odd divisor. Hence $k_{0}$ must be even, so by definition $k_{0} = 2 \times k_{1}$ where $k_{1} \in \mathbb{Z}$. So now $n = 2 \times k_{1} \times O$. Now apply the same argument for $k_{1}$.

Comment: Cont... This continues for some finite number of times (since ultimately $n$ is finite) and when it terminates (then $k_{m}$ should have been $1$) it should be of the desired form of $2^{k} \times O$